# React render to string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

i want to convert react component to string . ( here the component can have api calls useEffect etc).

example Component .

```
function Home() {
  const [state, changeState] = useState("stack");
  useEffect(() => {
    changeState("stackoverflow");
  }, []);
  return (
      <div>{state}</div>
      );
}
```

now the return output should be something like this `<div>stackoverflow</div>`
not like this `<div>stack</div>`

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. The code that you've provided does give "stackoverflow" and not "stack". Perhaps if you were to provide a better example we could help.

Comment: I want to convert react component to string in the sever (Nodejs) . we have renderToString from react but that is returning initial value as a string not the updated component .